# bias estimating the proportion in pooled population

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, bias, pooling

Assuming we want to estimate the proportion of success and there are two stages. We will move to stage 2 only when the number of success is greater than equal to a threshold (say 5) in stage 1. And we want to use stage 1 and 2's information to estimate the proportion of success.

If we observe 3 successes out of 30 in stage 1 and 14 successes out of 100 in stage 2, can we simply say the estimated proportion is 17/130=?

I suspect there would be bias upward or downward as we include the stage 1's result knowing its success.

Any suggestions to address this bias and estimate the proportion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems garbled, maybe with typos. Please clarify: Exactly what is Stage 1? Under what circumstances do we move to Stage 2? If we move to Stage 2, exactly what is it? If we have only Stage 1, how do we estimate P(Success); if we have both stages, how do we estimate P(Success).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. In stage 1, for samples 30 if we observe greater or equal to 5 success then move to stage 2 where we will collect larger sample 100.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation, I think you are right that there will be
bias, and for the reason you give. If you start off with an estimate that
is 'large' you try again, possibly substituting a smaller estimate based on results from more trials.

**Simulation with Phases 1 & 2:** I simulated the experiment a million times for each of three success
probabilities $p = 1/10, 1/6, 3/10,$ respectively. The event `cond` occurs if
we go on to Stage 2. The estimate `ext` is the average of results based on
30 trials if only Stage 1 is used, and the average of results based on 130 trials
if both stages are used. [Notice that if $p = 1/6,$ then the average count at
Phase 1 is $5.]$

```
set.seed(1118);  m = 10^6; p = .1
x1 = rbinom(m, 30, p);  x2 = rbinom(m, 100, p)
cond = (x1 >= 5)
est = x1/30;  est[cond] = (x1[cond]+x2[cond])/130
mean(est);  mean(cond)
[1] 0.08819467  # est seems < 0.1
[1] 0.175508    # aprx P(Go to Stage 2)

p = 1/6
x1 = rbinom(m, 30, p);  x2 = rbinom(m, 100, p)
cond = (x1 >= 5)
est = x1/30;  est[cond] = (x1[cond]+x2[cond])/130
mean(est);  mean(cond)
[1] 0.1461873   # est seems < 1/6
[1] 0.57612     # aprx P(Go to Stage 2)

p =.4
x1 = rbinom(m, 30, p);  x2 = rbinom(m, 100, p)
cond = (x1 >= 5)
est = x1/30;  est[cond] = (x1[cond]+x2[cond])/130
mean(est);  mean(cond)
[1] 0.3996667   # est seems near 0.4
[1] 0.998444    # aprx P(Go to State 2)
```

**Straightforward simulation with 130 trials:** If you just go ahead and use $n = 130$ trials from the start (with no Phase 1 or Phase 2 contingencies), you get very good estimates with a million iterations:

```
mean(rbinom(10^6, 130, .1)/130)
[1] 0.1000389  # aprx .1
mean(rbinom(10^6, 130, 1/6)/130)
[1] 0.1666442  # aprx 1/6
mean(rbinom(10^6, 130, .4)/130)
[1] 0.3999704  # aprx .4
```

**Toward a general analytic solution:** To find a general analytic solution for any $p,$ you need to start by figuring out such things as: (a) the probability of going on to Stage 2, (b) the expected
value of the estimate $E(\hat p_1)$ for Stage 1 only, (c) the estimate $E(\hat p_1 | \text{Stop at Phase 1})$, and (d) the estimate
$E(\hat p_b)$ if both stages are used.